# SQL table's column referencing different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a table called `Comment` which stores comments of users. This `Comment` table should reference different types of content: revisions, posts, and other comments (using tables `Revision`, `Post`, and `Comment` respectively).

How should I design the database so that this can be achieved?

**Edit**: Just for clarity.

I have several types of content: Revision, Post, Comment. It is possible that other types may be addded in the future. For each type of content a user is able to comment. How do I construct my tables and references so that a `Comment` can be linked to the different types of content.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you describe your objective in more detail. The question is: Why to use generalization for Comments and not for Posts, Revisions etc.

Comment: Which part is lacking? I will update it as needed. I thought my description is concise.

Comment: So you allow comments on comments? I meant that we do not see attributes of the types/classes and do not know what makes them distinct one from another.

Comment: If you are re-inventing the WP wheel, see this for "meta":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta